# EE v2.5.2 Updated banned user email list - now php error

Tags: php, expressionengine

In ExpressionEngine, I was updating the list of banned user emails. After I selected update, my screen went blank. I have tried/googled everything I could think. I was able to set the debug, but I still cannot find my solution. My website is

> http://www.planpreparereact.uga.edu/.

I am using `EE v2.5.2`. Here are the features for my webhosting:
`Apache 2.2.3`
`Perl 5.8.8 CGI`
`Python 2.4.3 CGI`
`PHP 5.3.3` running in `FastCGI` mode
`Virtual Hosting`
`sqlite 3.3.6`
`MySQL 5.0.77`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you may actually have a database error that is causing other problems.  The very last error on your page shows that the query is not passing a site_id value.

Comment: How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a recent backup of your config file?

`system/expressionengine/config/config.php`

If so you might try restoring it to the previous state (make a back up of your current file first).